# Long format data - fill episode based on conditional previous episode

Tags: performance, validation, r

The data are organised as *long format data*. 4 individuals are observed during 4 or 5 days (`BCSID` is the name of the *unique key*). Basically, the data describe activities performed during these 4-5 days. `START` describe the start time of activities and `MAINACT` the activities.

The data:

```
data = structure(list(BCSID = c("B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", 
                     "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10001N", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", 
                     "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10004R", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", 
                     "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10010P", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q"), DAY = c("1", 
                                                                                     "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                                                     "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
                                                                                     "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
                                                                                     "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
                                                                                     "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                                                     "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
                                                                                     "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
                                                                                     "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
                                                                                     "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
                                                                                     "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
                                                                                     "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                                                     "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
                                                                                     "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
                                                                                     "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
                                                                                     "4", "4", "5", "5", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                                                     "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
                                                                                     "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
                                                                                     "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5"), START = c("00:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "00:30:00", "10:00:00", "10:05:00", "10:35:00", "11:00:00", "11:03:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "11:15:00", "14:00:00", "14:30:00", "14:40:00", "14:45:00", "15:05:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "16:15:00", "17:00:00", "20:00:00", "00:00:00", "09:30:00", "10:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "10:30:00", "10:50:00", "11:15:00", "12:50:00", "14:00:00", "14:20:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "14:40:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:45:00", "00:00:00", "00:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "01:00:00", "10:30:00", "12:00:00", "12:30:00", "12:45:00", "12:50:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "13:30:00", "14:30:00", "18:30:00", "19:30:00", "20:00:00", "00:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "10:00:00", "10:15:00", "11:00:00", "11:15:00", "12:30:00", "13:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "15:30:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "21:30:00", "22:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "00:00:00", "07:30:00", "08:10:00", "08:15:00", "08:30:00", "09:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "09:45:00", "11:45:00", "12:45:00", "13:45:00", "14:15:00", "15:15:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "15:30:00", "15:45:00", "16:30:00", "17:15:00", "17:45:00", "18:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "18:30:00", "20:30:00", "23:20:00", "23:30:00", "00:00:00", "08:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "08:30:00", "09:15:00", "09:30:00", "11:10:00", "13:00:00", "13:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "18:15:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "21:00:00", "21:30:00", "22:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "23:00:00", "23:02:00", "23:15:00", "00:00:00", "07:00:00", "07:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "08:30:00", "08:45:00", "09:45:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "15:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "20:45:00", "22:00:00", "22:15:00", "22:45:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "00:00:00", "07:45:00", "08:00:00", "08:30:00", "09:00:00", "09:10:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "09:30:00", "11:41:00", "12:15:00", "12:45:00", "13:00:00", "13:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "14:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00", "22:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "00:00:00", "06:45:00", "07:50:00", "08:05:00", "08:55:00", "09:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "17:00:00", "17:20:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "19:25:00", "23:00:00", "23:25:00", "00:00:00", "00:15:00", "10:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "12:15:00", "18:00:00", "18:10:00", "18:45:00", "19:20:00", "19:45:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "22:00:00", "22:35:00", "00:00:00", "04:00:00", "10:00:00", "13:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "13:25:00", "16:35:00", "17:15:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "20:40:00", "21:00:00", "22:50:00", "23:00:00", "23:50:00", "00:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "01:45:00", "06:45:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "17:00:00", "18:50:00", "23:15:00", "23:45:00", "00:00:00", "00:15:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "00:00:00", "07:00:00", "08:00:00", "08:30:00", "08:50:00", "13:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "14:30:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:30:00", "00:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:30:00", "13:00:00", "18:30:00", "20:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "21:30:00", "00:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:30:00", "09:00:00", "09:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "09:35:00", "10:00:00", "10:30:00", "13:30:00", "14:00:00", "15:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "18:00:00", "22:00:00", "00:00:00", "07:00:00", "07:30:00", "08:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "08:40:00", "12:30:00", "13:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "20:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                             "00:00:00", "00:20:00"), MAINACT = c("-11", "1704", "1302", "1301", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1507", "603", "1301", "101", "502", "1704", "1507", "1404", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "8888", "603", "1507", "101", "-11", "1302", "1301", "1507", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "704", "101", "1704", "1704", "3102", "1002", "1704", "3101", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "101", "-11", "1704", "1302", "1302", "1507", "603", "2902", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "3201", "812", "1704", "1704", "3701", "101", "-11", "1302", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1301", "3101", "1001", "1507", "1006", "2101", "2902", "1704", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "8888", "1704", "1302", "-11", "1302", "1302", "1507", "1301", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1702", "1001", "2902", "2901", "2101", "2502", "3801", "3001", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "3504", "1301", "3503", "3101", "1507", "1301", "2601", "1702", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1302", "1606", "1302", "1301", "502", "101", "101", "1001", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "101", "101", "502", "3504", "3101", "2902", "1507", "3702", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1408", "3801", "2902", "2101", "1408", "1302", "1302", "1302", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1606", "1302", "1408", "1503", "2902", "1705", "2701", "2803", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "2805", "2902", "3701", "1408", "1301", "1302", "1302", "1606", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1302", "1301", "1507", "603", "4010", "3701", "2101", "4008", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1507", "603", "1301", "2101", "1702", "1507", "3504", "2701", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1302", "-11", "1302", "502", "2502", "102", "101", "103", "101", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "502", "502", "1704", "1702", "2902", "1702", "1704", "-11", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1302", "1302", "1702", "2502", "1702", "2902", "1702", "1704", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1702", "2507", "-11", "1702", "1302", "1702", "3601", "1704", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "2801", "1702", "2902", "1702", "1704", "3801", "3601", "603", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1302", "1606", "1601", "1302", "502", "101", "103", "101", "502", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "2901", "1702", "1704", "-11", "1302", "-11", "1302", "1507", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "502", "101", "103", "101", "502", "1704", "701", "1301", "1606", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1302", "502", "301", "301", "1704", "2901", "1702", "-11", "1702", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1302", "1302", "1507", "603", "601", "601", "1507", "603", "1006", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "1507", "3201", "-11", "1302", "1507", "1301", "502", "103", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "101", "1704", "1301", "1704", "1702", "1302"), eorder2 = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              20, 21, 22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              11, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2)), .Names = c("BCSID", "DAY", "START", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "MAINACT", "eorder2"), row.names = c(NA, 231L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data look like this:

> ```
>      BCSID DAY    START MAINACT eorder2
> 28 B10001N   2 16:00:00    3101      12
> 29 B10001N   2 16:45:00     101      13
> 30 B10001N   3 00:00:00     -11       1
> 31 B10001N   3 00:30:00    1704       2
> 32 B10001N   3 01:00:00    1302       3
> 33 B10001N   3 10:30:00    1302       4
> ```

The variable `eorder2` denotes the order of activities **per day**. The first observation (`eorder2 == 1`) beginning at midnight (00:00:00) is or should be sleeping.

The missing sleep is denoted **-11**. What I need to do is to *fill* this missing sleep with a *proxy* sleep denoted **1606**.

However, I need to specify several conditions for this *proxy* sleep:

- I need to exclude DAY 1.
- I need to "target" the first episode of each day.
- Finally, I want that the previous last episode is **1302** or **3201** and that the first next episode after **-11** is **1302**.

Here, for example, Row **220** is a missing that fulfill the conditions. It is the first episode of the day and it is preceded by **3201** and followed by **1302**.

> ```
>       BCSID DAY    START MAINACT eorder2
> 218 B10011Q   3 18:00:00    1507      12
> 219 B10011Q   3 22:00:00    3201      13
> 220 B10011Q   4 00:00:00     -11       1
> 221 B10011Q   4 07:00:00    1302       2
> 222 B10011Q   4 07:30:00    1507       3
> ```

I was thinking doing something like this:

First, specifying some Row conditions:

```
ep2 = which( data$eorder2 == 1 & # first episode 
           data$DAY != 1 & # not day 1 
           data$MAINACT == '-11') # missing activities
```

Then fill the missing **-11** with a line of code like this:

```
data[ep2, 'MAINACT'] [ data[ep2-1,'MAINACT'] == '1302' | data[ep2-1,'MAINACT'] == '3201' & data[ep2+1,'MAINACT'] == '1302'  ] <- '1606'
```

Using `ep2-1` for targeting the previous episode and `ep2+1` the following episode.

This code seems to work. Alternative ideas or corrections are very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first write (or find) a function for shifting a vector `x` by a given number of observations `k`. The `stat` package has a `lag` function but it only allows to shift in one direction (`k` has to be `>= 0`)... Here is such a function that will work both ways, with positive or negative `k`:

```
LAG <- function(x, k) {
   if (k == 0) {
      x
   } else if (k > 0) {
      c(rep(NA, k), head(x, -k))
   } else {
      c(tail(x, k), rep(NA, -k))
   }   
}
```

Then, you can create a boolean vector telling if each row meets all the conditions or not:

```
need_replace <- with(data, eorder2 == 1 &
                           DAY != 1 &
                           MAINACT == '-11' &
                           LAG(MAINACT, +1) %in% c('1301', '1302') &
                           LAG(MAINACT, -1) == '1302')
```

And finally, do the substitution:

```
data$MAINACT[need_replace] <- '1606'
```

A few more comments:

1. I created a vector of TRUE/FALSE rather than a vector of indices like you did with `which`. Both work but it is less typing without `which`.
2. See that I used `with(data, ...)` so I did not have to type `data$` over and over. This also makes your code shorter and easier to read.
3. I used `%in%` instead of two `==` statements separated by `|`. That's another good function to know (imagine having many more than two allowed values...)
4. Be careful that `&` has higher priority than `|` so what you had written was equivalent to `statement1 | (statement2 & statement 3)` which is not the same as what I think you had in mind: `(statement1 | statement2) & statement3`. Priority rules are documented under `?Syntax`.
5. As it stands, none of the rows in your example data match all the conditions you have specified so please let me know if I misunderstood something, I am sure it will be a simple fix.